# list of dependencies of a ractive instance

Tags: ractivejs

[The documentation](http://docs.ractivejs.org/latest/dependants) indicates that a list of the dependencies of a Ractive instance is available with the _deps property. I'm just getting 'undefined', and I'm not even finding such a property defined in the source code.

I'm thinking that maybe the docs might not be accurate on this.

Can anyone please tell me how to investigate the dependencies of a Ractivejs instance?

Comment: Eek! That is out of date, and relates to stuff that was never part of the API proper. We should remove that. Can you explain in more detail what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm debugging a problem, so I don't yet have a good handle on things. My best current guess is that an attribute somewhere deep in the dependency tree was not initialized. So I was looking for some insight into the structure.